# Как сделать узор фона в css?

Tags: html, css

Есть фон, на него нужно наложить вот такой узор. Как он реализуется? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что его размещать абсолютно на весь родитель я знаю, не понимаю, как сам узор сделать.

Comment: Взять кусочек узора, в виде `data:` засунуть в `background`.

Comment: А можно пример, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 6):

Возьмем в качестве паттерна такое изображение (косая черта 8x8 пикселей):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И закодируем его в Base64. Теперь его можно использовать в качестве фона.

```css
.with-pattern {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.with-pattern:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /* Повторяемый паттерн. Значение repeat как раз отвечает за повторение. */
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAAAAADhZOFXAAAAMUlEQVR4AQXAwQmAMAADwAymitL9/9VCcJKTvKBbQPcZ6DEFPR9Cr4XovSDfWCCjoD/SYTeuAZE4IQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .1;
  /* Наложение пропускает клики сквозь себя */
  pointer-events: none;
}
img {
  /* Для демонстрации */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-pattern">
  <img src="https://satyr.io/300x150/3">
</div>
```

От длины и наклона исходной черты зависит плотность заполнения.

Реализацию узора можно сделать и без кодирования изображения в Base64, просто так экономится 1 запрос на сервер. Вот пример с обычной картинкой:

```css
.with-pattern {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.with-pattern:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /* Повторяемый паттерн. Значение repeat как раз отвечает за повторение. */
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRaES.png") repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .1;
  /* Наложение пропускает клики сквозь себя */
  pointer-events: none;
}
img {
  /* Для демонстрации */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-pattern">
  <img src="https://satyr.io/300x150/4">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как можно уменьшить расстояние между линиями в первом варианте и сделать некую размытость фона?

Comment: @Александр, я же написал, измените наклон или уменьшите размер изображения. Например, до 4х4.

Answer (score 6):

Вот вам готовое решение:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container .pattern {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 2px, rgba(155,155,155,.45) 2px, rgba(155,155,155,.45) 4px);
  z-index:2;
  opacity: .2;
}
.image-container .img {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://www.caranddriver.com/images/16q2/667349/2017-porsche-911-turbo-first-drive-review-car-and-driver-photo-669210-s-340x208.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 104%;
  height: 104%;
  left: -2%;
  top: -2%;
  filter: blur(5px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 -moz-filter: blur(5px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
 -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<div class="pattern"></div>
<div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Что и где редактировать, думаю, разберетесь. Есть так же масса других решений. Используйте [готовые паттерны](http://subtlepatterns.com/) как фон для класса .pattern и играйтесь прозрачностью, для достижения оптимального результата.

Answer (score 2):

Простой вариант - выставить фоном *.png или *.svg с прозрачностью. Такой вариант использую я в своих проектах ([пример](http://www.gambala.pro/projects/pizzeria)), т.к. во внешнее изображение можно поместить какой-угодно орнамент, с какими угодно формами, блюром и прозрачностью.

Другой вариант - использовать повторяющийся линейный градиент. Реализуется полностью в CSS, поддерживается всеми современными браузерами кроме IE8.

Оба варианта в коде:

```css
section {
  background: #bada55 url(http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/300/200/3);
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 0;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

section.-striped-with-image:after {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/G5ll432.png);
}

section.-striped-with-gradient:after {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 3px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 3px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 15px
  );
}
```

```html
<section class="-striped-with-image"></section>
<section class="-striped-with-gradient"></section>
```

[Или смотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/698e0dm8/)